# Derivative of the Square Root of a Logarithm

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=ln(\sqrt {\frac {6x+3}{3x-9}})$

Find $f'(x)$.

I've tried the method involving distributing the natural log and making it $(1/2)\ln(6x+3)-(1/2)\ln(3x-9)$.

Comment: why didnt you proceed further?

Comment: I did. I just got the wrong answer, so I started back from there

Comment: Yes, both the numerator and the denominator are under the square root

Comment: I changee the title, since "logarithmic differentiation" means something different from what you are doing here.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac {d(logG(x))}{dx}= \frac 1{logG(x)} \frac {d(G(x))}{dx}$$

$$df/dx=\frac {\frac {6}{6x+3} - \frac {3}{3x-9}}2$$

which can be simplified to

$$\frac {-7}{2(2x+1)(x-3)}$$

Comment: Thank you. I ended up getting that answer myself. I got the problem wrong because I didn't further simplify the fraction from 1/(2x+1)-1/(2x-6)

Comment: I am happy that it helped :). But hey from where did you get 2x-6 ...

Comment: I distributed the ln to get (1/2)ln(6x+3)-(1/2)ln(3x-9), then getting (1/2)(6/6x+3)-(1/2)(3/3x-9). I factored the two terms getting 1/(2x+1)-1/2(x-3). I got (2x-6) from multiplying the 2 with x-3

Comment: Oh yes, silly me 2(x-3)=2x-6. Enjoy learning.